# Fixing non-manifold edge for 3d printing

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, 3d-printing, external-applications

I need to print out a toothed ring but it prints out as a disk, ie with the ring filled in.  On checking the stl file in blender it has non-manifold edges and I think these confuse the printer.
I can see that the inner part of the ring is non-manifold in *Edit Mode* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

The file is at:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3_qq9691bVuSEduM3Y5bWdRY0k

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry

Answer (score 4):

While removing  doubles with a high merge distance of 0.1 or more will remove some of the problem, fixing the non-manifold issue manually will take a very long time as you need to fix each and every errant vertex.

However, if you don't need to maintain the exact same mesh and can live with a very very close reconstruction of it, you can fix the non-manifold issue automatically by using the [remesh modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html), and then the [decimate modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html) to reduce the polycount back to sanity.

Here's the setup:
[image]

After adding the modifiers with the parameter values specified above, you can either directly export to STL *(File --> Export --> Stl)* or apply the modifiers and then export.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer which has enabled me to progress with a 3D print of an orrery from thingiverse

Comment: Just a note that it may make more sense to print this ring "upside-down", with the flat part on the printer bed. Otherwise supporting material may be needed.